# Is geosearch activated on all Wikipedias?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am finding inconsistencies in the results reported by different wikipedias and between API and pages in the same one.

This search

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsbbox=43.60834750781285|16.456582641601567|43.50834750781285|16.55658264160157&format=json&gslimit=500

reports 6 results

while the equivalent one

https://hr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsbbox=43.60834750781285|16.456582641601567|43.50834750781285|16.55658264160157&format=json&gslimit=500

returns none even though this page https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klis has geographical coordinates, and should be returned by the above search.

Is it possible that geosearch isn't activated on some of the wikipedias - in this case the Croatian one?

Comment: Geodata is activated on hr.wiki: https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posebno:Verzija but the coordinates for that article don't seem to be stored in a way that's accessible to the API. If you're looking for a workaround, it's probably possible to use en.wiki and then look for equivalent articles on other wikis via wikidata where the interwiki links are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geosearch on Wikipedia is rather unreliable because coordinates can be stored in many different ways in an article. Although it seems that it works better on the English Wikipedia than on the Croatian one, also your query result of the English Wikipedia is not complete. For example, it does not include https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen,_Croatia and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mravince even though these two places are located within your bounding box.

For doing geosearch, I suggest to use the [Wikidata query service](https://query.wikidata.org) instead of the Mediawiki API. The following query returns you all places within the bounding box with an article on Croation Wikipedia: https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Abox%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3AcornerWest%20%22Point%2816.456582641601567%2043.60834750781285%29%22%5E%5Egeo%3AwktLiteral%20.%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3AcornerEast%20%22Point%2816.55658264160157%2043.50834750781285%29%22%5E%5Egeo%3AwktLiteral%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fplace%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fhr.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%7D

Note however, that this query does not search coordinates stored on Wikipedia but on Wikidata.

Answer (score 0):

The geosearch was not activated at the time the question was asked. I added a question in August 2021 about the same topic on the technical topics page of the Croatian Wikipedia, and quickly got a response confirming that the feature had been activated as a result of my asking.

[https://hr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedija:Kafić/Tehnička_pitanja](https://hr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedija:Kafi%C4%87/Tehni%C4%8Dka_pitanja)

That is great news for those of us that enjoy apps like V for Wiki.